# Binding to properity of properity

Tags: wpf

I need show album cover photo and title. In data context I have Album object but I do not know how to show CoverPhoto I need Bind ImageBrush ImageSource to CoverPhoto.ThumbnailSource but how? I can not use DataContext="{Bindind CoverPhoto}" ImageSource="{Binding ThumbnailSource}"

WPF:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AlbumItem">
    <Grid Width="360" Height="240">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding CoverPhoto, Converter={StaticResource ThumbnailConverter}, ConverterParameter=340}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Center" />
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="12">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ItemHeaderText}" Text="{Binding Title, Converter={StaticResource TextPlainConverter}, ConverterParameter=140}" MaxHeight="40" />
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ItemSubheaderText}" Text="{Binding StartTime, Converter={StaticResource TextPlainConverter}, ConverterParameter=280}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

C#:

```
class Album
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public Photo CoverPhoto { get; set; }
}

class Photo
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    BitmapImage PhotoSource { get; }
    BitmapImage ThumbnailSource { get; }
}
```

Comment: ImageSource="{Binding CoverPhoto.ThumbnailSource, Converter={StaticResource ThumbnailConverter}, ConverterParameter=340}"

Comment: What are the binding errors in the output window?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `ImageSource="{Binding CoverPhoto.ThumbnailSource}"` to avoid changing the `DataContext`.

Also note that you may need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the `Album` and `Photo` classes.  Without this, changes made in code behind won't be reflected in the front end.

Comment: I am new in WPF, I did not know the error in the output window. thanks
Error: Cannot get 'ThumbnailSource' value (type 'Object') from type 'PhotoGallery.Photo.PhotoFactory+PhotoInfoWeb, PhotoGallery.Windows, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. BindingExpression: Path='ThumbnailSource' DataItem='PhotoGallery.Photo.PhotoFactory+PhotoInfoWeb, PhotoGallery.Windows, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image' (Name='null'); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource').

Comment: @Lenny It sounds like your `PhotoInfoWeb` class doesn't have `ThumbnailSource` property...

Comment: The code is simplified, in fact Photo is interface and instance creates abstract factory so there must have ThumbnailSource

Comment: @Lenny This is the key part: `Cannot get 'ThumbnailSource' value (type 'Object') from type 'PhotoGallery.Photo.PhotoFactory+PhotoInfoWeb`  Check the `PhotoInfoWeb` nested class in `PhotoFactory`

Comment: and what it mean + in "PhotoGallery.Photo.PhotoFactory+PhotoInfoWeb"

Comment: @Lenny THat's the PhotoInfoWeb nested class inside of PhotoFactory